# Using angular-js 'ng-repeat' directive in nav-tabs with each tab having same html but different name and id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is a small list of [nav tabs](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp) in my code, actually the list is long. So using ng-repeat would be helpful. Only problem I'm facing is that although the html for all list items is same, the name of each list item ( Mercedes, Ferrari, Red Bull, Williams) is different, and also each has a different id. So can I use ng-repeat at all? If not is there a shorter method for this, or do I have to write all the html for all the list items again and again?

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="active"><a role="tab" href="#merc" data-toggle="tab">Mercedes</a></li>
                    <li><a role="tab" href="#ferr" data-toggle="tab">Ferrai</a></li>
                    <li><a role="tab" href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red Bull</a></li>
                    <li><a role="tab" href="#wil" data-toggle="tab">Williams</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div class="tab-content"  style="padding-bottom:50px; padding-top:20px">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="merc">
                        Some html
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="ferr">
                        Some html
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="wil">
                        Some html
                    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate automatically a id when you click a tab.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.cars = ["Audi", "Mercedes"];

    $scope.setTempItem = function(item) {
        $scope.currentItem = item;

    }

});
```

So the html should be something like this:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <a href="#{{currentItem}}" ng-click="setTempItem(car)">{{car}}</a>
    </li>
        </ul>

    <div id="{{currentItem}}" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel">
            {{currentItem}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){

$scope.cars = ["Audi","Mercedes"];

$scope.setTempItem = function(item){
     $scope.currentItem= item;

}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li ng-repeat="car in cars">
  <a href="#{{currentItem}}" ng-click="setTempItem(car)">{{car}}</a>
  </li>
            </ul>
      
        <div id="{{currentItem}}" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel">
                {{currentItem}}
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. However, can we put one of the list items (say Mercedes) as active class, so that when the page loads, html of that item is shown, without actually clicking on the Mercedes?

Comment: Yep, you can initialize currentItem taking one item of array. Something like   $scope.currentItem = $scope.cars[0];

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="car in cars" class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="{{car}}">
    Some html
</div>
```

Here is CodePen example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJoaYx

Comment: I'm not familiar with using the $index variable, how and why is it used? Could you guide me a bit over this part?

Comment: $index is a variable which you can use inside ng-repeat directive to access the rendered element number.

Comment: SHIVANG AGARWAL, here is a codepen without using $index: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJoaYx